# RewriteRule redirect everything except one folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm not very good with mod_rewrite but I really need it now.

I have the whole new website in an folder called `site`. So if you need to go the new website the URL would look like `http://domain.com/site/...`. Now I need to exclude the `site` from the URL but still point it to `/site/` EXCEPT for one folder called `upload`. How can I do this?

So `http://domain.com/anything.ext` and `http://domain.com/anyfolder` would point to `http://domain.com/site/...` except for `domain.com/upload` which still points to `domain.com/upload`.

Then another question, is assume this is only good for a temporary solution or doesn't it really matter (thinking of speed and efficiency)?

Answer (score 15):

(Assuming you are putting the rules in a .htaccess file in your document root) use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^upload
RewriteRule (.*) site/$1 [L]
```

If you are putting it into httpd.conf, you need to change it slightly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/upload
RewriteRule (.*) /site$1 [L]
```

Regarding the second question, I personally don't like mod_rewrite and certainly wouldn't use it as a permanent solution unless you absolutely have to. This is because mod_rewrite is quite inefficient, especially on busy servers, because it has to run at least one regular expression on every single incoming request. You should always use the `[L]` flag to ensure that no more rules than necessary are processed.

It is always more efficient to structure your directories in the same way as the application refers to them. The above should get you working, but try not to leave it in place for too long.

I'm sure you know this already, but [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is the mod_rewrite documentation.

Comment: When I use it (.htaccess code) it shows an Internal Server Error. I couldn't find what is wrong.

Comment: My clients hosting company is being a pain in the ass. They don't give support on htaccess issues and therefor don't want to send me any logs.. They did say that they did not limit any htaccess functions. Assuming my code is ok, I should just keep contacting the hosting company or can there be another cause of the Internal Server Error? (dont forget that it only shows when .htaccess contains the code from above)

Comment: Does it work if you try and reach by including `/site` in the URL? If not, remove/rename the .htaccess file and try... basically just trying to make sure your site actually works before we play with mod_rewrite...